# How to draw a line using a texture with Cocos2D

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

How can I draw a line using a texture in Cocos2D? Specifically I'm looking to create an effect similar to: http://www.slickcar.com/products/purple-neon.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this repository https://github.com/hiepnd/cocos2d-ext/. CCNode+Ext.h has a function called (drawLineFrom:to:texture:baseLength:stretch:). Hope it helps :)