# cocos2d: apply texture to perimeter of a polygon

Tags: ios, cocos2d, texture

I could not find any answer in the site so I decided to post my first question on Stackoverflow.

I am working with cocos2d 2.0 for iPhone and I need to apply a texture/pattern **only to the perimeter of a shape** like the grass in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD1nq.png).

More specifically I have already managed to fill the area of a polygon using the object PRFilledPolygon from [PRKit](https://github.com/asinesio/cocos2d-PRKit):

```
NSMutableArray *polygonPoints = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
[polygonPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:ccp(100,100)]];
[polygonPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:ccp(100,200)]];
// more points added here....

CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"ground.png"];
PRFilledPolygon *filledPolygon = [[PRFilledPolygon alloc] initWithPoints:polygonPoints andTexture:texture];
[self addChild:filledPolygon z:0];
```

So what I need now is to be able to apply "grass.png" to the perimeter of filledPolygon.
(I know the perimeter has no width so it cannot be "filled" with a texture but I would like to be able to specify a width value in order to identify a 2d space adjacent the perimeter where to apply the texture).

I hope I was clear in explaining my problem and thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try to draw 1) the perimeter lines as a texture filled polygon too. 2) create susscesive CCSprites that could be arranged on the polygon perimeter. 3) or something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762838/how-to-draw-a-line-using-a-texture-with-cocos2d

Comment: Yes I think I can create a polygon based on the perimeter, fill it with grass.png and place is under the area-polygon. Thank you.